# TypeScript: access global var from a class without import

Tags: javascript, static, global-variables, typescript

I got this module like this:

```
module MyModule {
    export class Constants {
        public static WIDTH:number = 100;
        public static HEIGHT:number = 100;
        ....
    }
} 
export = MyModule;
```

Now I need to use MyModule.Constants.WIDTH in another class but I can't use import (I need to deliver this class js to a third party, and they don't use requirejs). Right now I use reference to get code checking but it keep giving this error (at transpilling time)

```
error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'MyModule'
```

What should I do now so I can use autocomplete and get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're not [mindplay](https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/466433) on the TypeScript forum otherwise I'm about to repeat myself.

`export` and `import` work together.  You should either be using both or neither.  If you check what the generated code looks like [with](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20MyModule%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Constants%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20static%20WIDTH%3anumber%20=%20100;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20static%20HEIGHT%3anumber%20=%20100;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0Aexport%20=%20MyModule;) and [without](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20MyModule%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Constants%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20static%20WIDTH%3anumber%20=%20100;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20static%20HEIGHT%3anumber%20=%20100;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) the `export` keyword you'll see that `export` causes a module to be built.  Since the third party can't use RequireJS I don't think this is what you want.

I would structure my classes like the following:

```
    // file pkg/Foo.ts
module company.pkg {
    export class Foo {}
}

    // file pkg2/Bar.ts
module company.pkg2 {
    export class Bar{}
}
```

Putting everything into the name space of your company minimizes the chance of a conflict with another library.  Classes know about each other using a reference `/// <reference path="..." />` which will allow it to compile.

Since you're not doing modules I would also compile to a single file using `--out filename.js`.  That gets all the files included in (usually) the right order.

Comment: I guess I am not very clear about my question. The code works fine, but just showing errors (I am using Webstorm) when I am writing/edit the code. so I just want to get rid of that error messages and the red mark.

Comment: The reference to MyModule at the top is correct, I can click on that reference and WebStorm opens MyModule file.

Comment: I'm going to guess a little bit here but I still think the problem is how you're using export but not import.  I suspect The TypeScript compiler is looking at the MyModule file, sees that MyModule is not globally accessible (because it's an exported symbol in a module) and thus can't be the global MyModule symbol accessed elsewhere.  If WebStorm thinks that its the same symbol it's actually wrong.